# How to plot horizontal confidence interval in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot horizontal confidence intervals on a plot using `ggplot2`. Here is a `head()` of some of the relevant columns of my dataframe that I am using. I need the points to be plotted at each `tbl$logFC`, and a horizontal cofidence interval from `tbl$CI_L` to `tbl$CI_R`.

```
> head(tbl[,c('logFC', 'CI_L', 'CI_R', "adj_P_Value","gene",'Group1','Group2', 'Study_ID')])
        logFC        CI_L       CI_R adj_P_Value  gene             Group1                   Group2 Study_ID
1 -0.09017596 -0.43955752 0.25920561           1 CD244               Male                   Female  GSE2461
2  0.08704844 -0.26134341 0.43544028           1 CD244 ulcerative colitis irritable bowel syndrome  GSE2461
3 -0.03501474 -0.12677636 0.05674688           1 CD244   nonlesional skin            lesional skin GSE27887
4  0.01096914 -0.08064105 0.10257932           1 CD244       pretreatment            posttreatment GSE27887
5 -0.03707265 -0.12407201 0.04992672           1 CD244         Infliximab         Before treatment GSE42296
6  0.07644834 -0.02849309 0.18138977           1 CD244          Responder             Nonresponder GSE42296
```

Here is my code so far:

```
p <- ggplot(data = tbl) +
  geom_point(aes(x = logFC, y = paste(Study_ID,"\n",Group2," \U2192 ",Group1,sep = ""))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(0.5,2)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(2/3,2)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(1.5,2)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = log(2,2)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = hLines) +
  labs(title = tbl$gene, y = "Contrasts", x = bquote(~Log[2]~'FC'))

  #geom_errorbarh(aes(y = ???, x = logFC, xmin = logFC - CI_L, xmax = logFC + CI_R))
```

Everything works up until the last line, where I am not sure how to specify the `y` value. I've tried doing the same kind of `paste()` I did in the beginning and that doesn't seem to work, and I've tried doing `y = rownames(y)` which also doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: First things first. Remove all `tbl$` from inside `aes` calls to avoid nasty surprises. You specify the data.frame within the `ggplot` call.

Comment: Try to use `coord_flip()`?

Comment: @MrSnake in what way? Please provide an example of how it would work instead of just a suggestion.

Comment: @Roland Made those changes you suggested.

Comment: What ***exactly*** isn't working when you use `ggstance::geom_errorbarh`? It can inherit the `x` and `y` aesthetics from your `ggplot(...)` call, so move those up from `geom_point`. Then it should work just fine.

Comment: @Brian I am not sure where you are getting `ggstance` from, but I am not using that. `geom_errorbarh` is from the `ggplot2` package.

Comment: @Brian moving the `aes()` from `geom_point` to `ggplot` made it work!

Comment: @KyleWeise, I forgot that was included in base `ggplot2`. `ggstance` is a great package with horizontal versions of lots of geoms.